# How to determine what was not-null property references a null or transient value in Spring/Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a complex set of code that has to go through my domain and merge some different entities, and that ends up having to merge a bunch of other entities. This is non-trivial code, so it's not something I can give an example of. The problem I have is that I'm getting a `Not-null property references a null or transient value`, but I can't figure out what entity is actually causing the problem. I've looked at the entity class type that is says has the null/transient value, but every time I see it loaded, I don't see any that have a null, or non-saved value in their references.

So far I haven't been able to find a way to trouble shoot this to get at what exactly hibernate thinks is missing the value it should have. If I could find what instance of the object it thinks is wrong, it would give me a clue where to look.

I've stepped through the hibernate code as best as I can, but so far I haven't actually been able to find an instance of the object that hibernate is complaining about.

As an addendum, the call that actually blows up is later in the code, and given the entity it is complaining about, the call itself (a delete call) that is blowing up does not have any unattached entities, I double checked that. So I think it's a case of hibernate flushing some things, and then finding out there is an issue, and blowing up there, even though the call itself isn't doing anything wrong.

Any advice as to how to track this particular object down?

Comment: You're going to have a hard time getting answers with a question like this. I would suggest incrementally stripping away extraneous parts of your code until you have a contained, reproducible example. Best case scenario, you'll have solved the problem by then. Worst case, you'll have some code to post.

Answer (score 0):

I'm totally with shmosel: Your question is very vague...

Nevertheless: I think one of the problem diagnosing exceptions like yours is hibernates flush behavior. As you probably know hibernate flushes the session cache at the end of a transaction or once it needs to (for example hibernate needs to flush if a `SELECT` statement involves querying a table which is affected by an not yet flushed `DELETE` statement).

The consequence is of course the time of the exception being raised has little to do with the time the exception is "produced".

If no other approach is available you can spam `flush` statements throughout your code. There is no beauty in it, but it will likely help you to narrow down the problem.